SliverFillRemaining is not scrolling when child is overflowing
My SliverFillRemaining is not scrolling when his child is taking more space than is available.
Here is my code
return Scaffold(
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: MainPadding(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        ProgressCirclesBoxSelection(),
                        AddressContainer(...),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        DottedBorder(...),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: widget.boxParams.sizes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {...}
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {...}
                      )
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );


I can't scroll it wherever I touch, also I tried to add NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to ListView.builder but it doesn't change anything

If I may ask the reason behind not using sliverList instead?

@Md.YeasinSheikh Lack of knowledge. I am working with CustomScrollView not so long, I am forgetting about all this slivers

I think you can give a try with SliverList that should do the job for you.

If I understand your needs correctly, you want a list of vertically scrolling items, and a button that remains statically in the bottom of the screen?
If so, I would probably rearrange your widget tree.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        width: size.width,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Your button"),
          onPressed: () {}
        )
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: MainPadding(
            child: CustomScrollView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: ProgressCirclesBoxSelection(),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: AddressContainer(...),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: const SizedBox(height: 16),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: DottedBorder(...),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: const SizedBox(height: 16),
                ),
                SliverList.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.boxParams.sizes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {...}
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }


I'm moving your ElevatedButton into the place of the bottomNavigationBar to keep it fixed at the bottom of the viewport, letting the rest of the items in the list scroll freely.
I'm wrapping all your fixed items in SliverToBoxAdapter. Depending on what they are (they might be Slivers idk) you can remove the wrapper. You could also add Padding to AddressContainer and DottedBorder to avoid having SizedBox widgets, but there's no problem keeping them.
Lastly I'm using SliverList for your boxParams items.


Unfortunately it didn't help.

Thank you for letting me know. I will make some adjustments to the widget tree and get back to you!

I have now updated my answer, please take a look again and see if this helps! @KarolWiśniewski

Yes, it is working, thank you so much
